# elegant way to test WSDL based continuation callouts

Tags: unit-test, callout, wsdl, asynchronous-testing

I've read this document about testing  [Asynchronous Callout from an Imported WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_callout_soap.htm).

But is there a way to do the same test without instantiate an HttpResponse? because copy-pasting a string with an entire xml is tedious and error proning.

Answer (score 1):

Codebeautify.org has this [online tool](http://codebeautify.org/string-builder) where you can convert a long xml to string. Check the screenshot below.

[image]